# YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Expected Commands[0] to be of string type:

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, yaml, aws-cli, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to build my project on AWS using CodeBuild. I have placed this buildspec file in the root directory. CodeBuild is able to read the file but it is unable to proceed forward. But I got the following error on CodeBuild.

CodeBuild Log Error:

```
> [Container] 2020/05/19 08:56:07 Waiting for agent ping 
> [Container] 2020/05/19 08:56:09 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE 
> [Container] 2020/05/1908:56:14 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE [Container] 2020/05/19 08:56:14 YAML location is myRepoPath/buildspec.yml [Container] 2020/05/19 08:56:14 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED 
> [Container] 2020/05/19 08:56:14 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Expected Commands[0] to be of string type: found subkeys instead at line 30, value of the key tag on line 29 might be empty
```

My buildspec.yaml file :

```
    version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk11

    commands:
      - apt-get update -y
      - apt-get install -y maven
      - pip3 install --upgrade awscli

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - sonar_host_url=""
      - sonar_project_key="$REPOSITORY_NAME"
      - sonar_username=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SONARQUBE_USER_CREDENTIAL_SECRET | jq -r '.SecretString' | jq -r '.username')
      - sonar_password=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SONARQUBE_USER_CREDENTIAL_SECRET | jq -r '.SecretString' | jq -r '.password')
      - git checkout $SOURCE_COMMIT

  build:
    commands:
      - builStatus=$(mvn install)
      - result=$(mvn clean sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=$sonar_project_key -Dsonar.host.url=$sonar_host_url -Dsonar.login=$sonar_username -Dsonar.password=$sonar_password)
      - echo $result

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo $buildStatus
      - buildComment=$(echo "Status of project build phase : $buildStatus")
      - aws codecommit post-comment-for-pull-request --pull-request-id $PULL_REQUEST_ID --repository-name $REPOSITORY_NAME --before-commit-id $DESTINATION_COMMIT --after-commit-id $SOURCE_COMMIT --content "$buildComment"
      - sonar_link=$(echo $result | egrep -o "you can browse http://[^, ]+")
      - sonar_task_id=$(echo $result | egrep -o "task\?id=[^ ]+" | cut -d'=' -f2)
```

Comment: I think this is because colon in `phase : $build`. Yaml [does not like](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/2769) colons with spaces in text foo much

Comment: yup, it did the job. colon was the issue. I thought inside a comment/String it won't matter. Anyways thanks @Marcin

Comment: Cool. I will make an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on the comment, the issue was the use of colon in `phase : $build`.

`yaml` has some problems when it encounters a space and `:` as indicated in the following GitHub issue:

- [YAML syntax error when string contains a colon + space](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/2769)

Answer (score 3):

The error was because of the `:` in the 30th line inside echo. As @Marcin mentioned YAML does not like colons with spaces in the text.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when I put an `echo` statement in my yml commands which tried to print a series of `-` characters just to style my output a bit
`- echo '--- got here ---'

had to take that out and put underscores `_`

Answer (score 0):

To handle the ":" and "-" in YML which are both very problematic,
I ended up doing the following in codebuild to get dashes and commas working in strings:

```
- colon=$(python -c "print(chr(58))")
- dash=$(python -c "print(chr(45))")
- field_to_hold="http${colon}//www.example${dash}site.com"
```

**Explanation:**

- `python -c` - calls python and executes the command `print(chr(58))`
- `chr(58)` - returns ":"
- `chr(45)` - returns "-"
- `print(chr(58))` - sends the ":" to the sys.out which is assigned/consumed by `colon` variable
- `print(chr(45))` - sends the "-" to the sys.out which is assigned/consumed
  by `dash` variable
- `${colon}` will substitute the `:` in the field_to_hold string value
- `${dash}` will substitute the `-` in the field_to_hold string value

**Caveats:**

1. `${colon}` will not substitute in a single quoted string, it must be double quoted *(ie - `"`)*
2. for each section that needs the colon or dash, you will have to copy the `colon=$(python -c "print(chr(58))")`, as the variables do not pass through from section to section (Not Documented, but found out by trial and error).
3. Requires *Python* on the *codebuild* server/template.
4. IF you do not have *python*, you might be able to do something similar with linux/java of converting *ascii value* 58 or 45 to *ascii character*.